# Java hibernate truncates time part from MySQL datetime while reading

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, truncated

I'm using hibernate 4.1.10 in my java console app and I've got a Model with following column:

```
@Column(name = "created_at", columnDefinition="datetime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;
```

I just want java to handle entire MySQL datetime properly. At now, it can only read the date part and the rest is truncated. I've got a simple test where I just print the getCreatedAt() property to stdout:

```
System.out.println(income.getCreatedAt());
```

and it prints out the following:

```
2012-05-11 00:00:00.0
2012-05-29 00:00:00.0
2012-05-30 00:00:00.0
2012-06-28 00:00:00.0
2012-07-30 00:00:00.0
2012-08-29 00:00:00.0
2012-09-28 00:00:00.0
2012-10-30 00:00:00.0
2012-11-29 00:00:00.0
2012-12-02 00:00:00.0
2012-12-21 00:00:00.0
2012-12-24 00:00:00.0
2013-01-30 00:00:00.0
2013-02-27 00:00:00.0
2013-02-27 00:00:00.0
```

This is my `show create table` for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `created_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `category_type_idx` (`type`),
 KEY `created_by_idx` (`created_by`),
 KEY `updated_by_idx` (`updated_by`),
 KEY `category_parent_id_category_id` (`parent_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `category_created_by_sf_guard_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `sf_guard_user` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `category_parent_id_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `category_updated_by_sf_guard_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `sf_guard_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I've been trying to follow several tuts/answers found on the web (also on stackoverflow) and decided to use java.util.Date with annotation instead of java.sql.Date (because the MySQL type is `datetime`). And this is all I've managed to achieve. What can I do to retrieve the time part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably data in the database already truncated. Try storing `Timestamp` instead of `Date`. For example

```
@Column(name = "created_at", length = 19)
public Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
    return this.createdAt;
}

setCreatedAt(new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
```

Comment: At first, I couldn't believe in what you wrote, but afterall, you were right. The data was already truncated. Thank you!